# How can I make node application see system variables on Google Cloud?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have variable set in my .bash_rc file:

```
whoami@cloudshell:~/source/NodePrototype (x-alcove-9999999)$ echo $APP_ENVIRONMENT
LIVE
```

Yet node.js application out of:

```
const app_environment_config=require('./APP_ENVIRONMENT/' + process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT)
```

produce

```
2019-02-21 14:18:16 default[20190221t141628]  Error: Cannot find module './APP_ENVIRONMENT/undefined'
```

Eventhough when I enter node shell:

```
whoami@cloudshell:~/source/NodePrototype (x-alcove-9999999)$ node
> process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT
'LIVE'
```

The same part works locally.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your Node app is being launched, because looks like is not running in an environment where that variable exists, to make sure print all your current env vars to make this sure: `console.log(process.env)`.

Also, a good practice, when you need something like that, is to use `.env` files with this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv is a good practice to pass configuration to your Node apps.